# Flask SQLAlchemy: like binary method

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

Raw SQL like this `select * from user where name like binary %中文%`, as for the utf-8 reason I need to use `like binary`, I know there is a `like` function in sqlalchemy

```
User.query.filter(User.name.like("%中文%")).all()
```

This not works in such situation of course

I can run raw SQL instead, but it will break other things

Is there any method work for `like binary`?

Comment: Ah I fix this by using raw sql in `filter` xD `from sqlalchemy import text User.query.filter(text("user.name like binary '%中文%'"))`, but still I am wonder if there is better or other solution